# redirect each new line of stderr to consecutive file

Tags: macos, bash, redirect, pipe, stderr

I want to redirect each new line of stderr, of a process, to a sequence of text files. 
How do I do that in bash?

I have tried:

```
myProcess 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep 'Parsed' > parsed.txt | tail -f parsed.txt > line.`date +%s`.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to read each line of the output and explicitly redirect it to a new file.

```
myProcess 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep 'Parsed' | tee parsed.txt | while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line" >> line.$(date +%s).txt
done
```

Note as well the use of `tee` to write each line from `grep` to both the file `parsed.txt` as well as the `while` loop that redirects each line to a per-second file.

Comment: Thank you Chepner. My problem seems to be the fast time of the output. I get severel lines per second.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

function splitter {
   grep 'Parsed' |
   while read L; do
      echo "$L" >> `date +%s`
   done
}

myProcess 2> >( splitter ) > /dev/null
```

Two comments:

- your trick with 2>&1 >/dev/null will also work, this is another way of doing that.
- in splitter I have to use '>>' not just '>' as chances are that there will be two lines printed in the same second, and in such case you would get just last line in your file.

Answer (score 0):

```
... | grep 'Parsed' > parsed.txt
```

You redirect all `grep` output to `parsed.txt`, so there's nothing left to be fed into the next pipe. Also, `tail` reads from either a pipeline or a file, not both at the same time.

If you want the same output to go to multiple files you need `tee`:

```
myProcess 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep 'Parsed' | tee f1.txt | tee f2.txt > f3.txt
```

Comment: Which new line? When you keep writing to the file, there'll continually be new lines. What is the actual problem you want to solve by doing this?

Comment: I am parsing a video stream to get the info about the structure.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't follow (may be my lack of knowledge about video processing), why would it help with that to capture lines in different output files? Wouldn't it be more sensible to have your script "translate" the lines into the structural information you're actually looking for?

Comment: In this particular situation, I am parsing a video stream to get the info about the structure. I need to get the aspect ratio at exact change. I have the same situation if I need to parse the system logs for video stream requests. So I tried to think how to put the question to have a general solution.

Comment: it is about a live video transport stream that comes over IP. The video needs to be converted. So I need the info before the conversion happens. The output is for Http Live Streaming which comes in small chunks. So each line of the parser contains info how the encoding of the stream should happen

Answer (score 0):

Another variant:

```
myprocess 2> >(sed 's/.*/echo "&">>$(date +%s)/e;d')
```

Needs gnu sed & bash should have support for process redirection.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the OS X Terminal does not return milliseconds and there were to many lines in for each timestamp file

The solution I found is like this:

I installed deamontools from:
http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/tai64n.html

To get the following utilities:
 
 tai64n
 tai64nlocal

With the command:

```
echo | tai64n | tai64nlocal
```

it returns:

```
2013-07-03 10:34:41.756602500
```

So my final script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

function splitter {
   grep 'Parsed' |
   while read L; do
    t=`echo | tai64n | tai64nlocal`
      echo "$L" >> parse."$t".txt
   done
}

myProcess 2> >( splitter ) > /dev/null
```

for each stderr new line.
Thank you everybody for the help.
This was my first question and it turned out great

Comment: sorry, I thought that it should be the same with bash, I changed the tag